# Issue with shading every other row in my table

Tags: html, css

I am displaying data on my webpage with a table and wanted to make every other row a different color. I have watched many videos on how to do this but when I follow the instructions, my table highlights every other row horizontally rather than vertically. I am using `nth-of-type(even)` but I have also tried using `nth-of-type(2n+0)` and `nth-of-type(odd)`. I am sure there is an issue with my code but I can't seem to find it, any suggestions? Please let me know if more code is needed as the code below is in a full front and back-end system. Thanks!

Screenshot of table - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJsTt.jpg (Issue with uploading image on Stack)

Here is the code:

```css
.customer_table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    
      .customer_table thead tr {
        background-color: #4cb59c;
        text-align: left;
      }
    
      .customer_table th,
      .customer_table td {
        padding: 12px 15px;
      }
    
      .customer_table tbody tr {
        border: 0.5px solid #16a583;
      }
    
      .customer_table tr :nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: #dcc79e;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="60%" class="customer_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Orders</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between pseudo class and element `.customer_table tr :nth-of-type(even)`. It should look like this: `.customer_table tr:nth-of-type(even)`

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to highlight every other row or every other column? (Confusion arises because of the statement that the rows are being highlighted vertically, not sure what that means)

Comment: Sorry, the columns are highlighting every other row from left to right whereas I want it to highlight every other row from top to bottom, hope this explanation is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the following to each `<td>` and `<th>`, see **Figure I**. If it doesn't work then there are probably other CSS rulesets that have a higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). See **Figure II**:

**Figure I**

```css
th:nth-of-type(odd),
td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #16a583;
}

th:nth-of-type(even),
td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #dcc79e;
}
```

**Figure II**

Add a class to `<table>`

```html
<table class="classA">
```

Then double that class selector in CSS

```css
table.classA.classA th:nth-of-type(odd),
table.classA.classA td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #16a583;
}

table.classA.classA th:nth-of-type(even),
table.classA.classA td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #dcc79e;
}
```

And if for some reason that doesn't work then you may have to resort to using `!important` which overrides pretty much everything but another `!important` proceeding it. **Note: use `!important` sparingly, it can easily become [a hindrance](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/) rather than being of any help**. See **Figure III**.

**Figure III**

```css
th:nth-of-type(odd),
td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #16a583 !important;
}

th:nth-of-type(even),
td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #dcc79e !important;
}
```

BTW, this goes without saying but for the sake of completeness, any CSS properties added previously having to do with `background` and any part of the `<table>` should be removed or made into a comment (ex `/* CSS content made inert by being a comment */`).

**Example**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

th, td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #930;
}

th:nth-of-type(odd),
td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #16a583;
}

th:nth-of-type(even),
td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #dcc79e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Orders</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just tried this but it is still highlighting horizontally :(

Comment: Hi @Joshuatb_02 see update. Also remove the old styles that have `background` properties.